# getting javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException error when decrypting

Tags: java, aes, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt text from a file but i am receiving the following error:

> `Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher`

I'm using AES 128 bit with AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding. Any idea why I am getting this error?
Here is my code:

```
public class AES_Encryption  {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = new Scanner(new File("src//plainText.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("src//cipherText.txt");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    FileWriter fstream2 = new FileWriter("src//decrpytedText.txt");
    BufferedWriter out2 = new BufferedWriter(fstream2);
    System.out.println("" + str);


    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGen.init(128);
    Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes());
    String ct = new String(cipherText);
    System.out.println( new String(cipherText, "UTF8") );
    out.append(ct);
    out.close();


    String cipherT = new Scanner(new File("src//cipherText.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    //byte[] decVal = Base64.decode(cipherT.getBytes());
    byte[] newPlainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherT.getBytes());
    String dt = new String(newPlainText, "UTF8");
    out2.append(dt);
    out2.close();
}
```

}

Comment: At which line are You getting this error?

Comment: @VishalK line 54: byte[] newPlainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherT.getBytes());

Answer (score 3):

Your error is treating the ciphertext as a string:

```
String ct = new String(cipherText); // <--- Noooo!
```

There will be values in your byte array that cannot be expressed as characters in the default charset.

*Always* treat your ciphertext as a byte array, even when reading or writing to files.

Comment: I don't see an error. Here's my theory: Someone else did the same thing in their code, and they *know* they're right because their code is working. So they downvoted your question. Then they left work and drove too fast for the slick roads because, after all, nothing bad ever happened before, and got in a car accident. They're ok, but when they finally got home they came back to this question and realized they were wrong and you were right, and they wish they could change their vote. Because they wish that, because they have learned, and because you were right all along, I'm giving you +1.

Comment: (And I don't use "LOL" lightly... my colleagues looked at me a little strangely as I chuckled)

Answer (score 1):

One get the IllegalBlockSizeException in following case as mentioned in [Cipher API documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal%28byte%5B%5D%29):

> **IllegalBlockSizeException - If this cipher is a block cipher, no padding has been requested (only in encryption mode), and the total input length of the data
>   processed by this cipher is not a multiple of block size**

In Your case you are Encrypting the String correctly , But while decryption you are treating the cipherText as `String` and then 
you are putting `cipherT.getBytes()` byte array in `doFinal` method of `Cipher`. The byte array conversion of String is not same as reading byte array from the file in binary mode. 
The functionality and limitation of `String.toBytes()` as mentioned in [String API documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) is as follows:

> **Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array. The
>   behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the
>   default charset is unspecified. The CharsetEncoder class should be
>   used when more control over the encoding process is required.**

What I suggest for you is to read the `cipherText.txt` `File`  in binary mode and then put the byte array you got after reading the file in `doFinal` method of `Cipher` . I have modified your code in following way:

```
public class AES_Encryption  {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = new Scanner(new File("plainText.txt")).useDelimiter("\\t").next();
    FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream("cipherText.txt");
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fstream);
    FileOutputStream fstream2 = new FileOutputStream("decrpytedText.txt");
    BufferedOutputStream out2 = new BufferedOutputStream(fstream2);
    System.out.println("INPUT String:\n" + str);


    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGen.init(128);
    Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes());
    System.out.println("ENCRYPTED String:\n"+new String(cipherText, "UTF8") );
    out.write(cipherText);
    out.flush();
    out.close();


    //String cipherT = new Scanner(new File("cipherText.txt")).nextLine();
    BufferedInputStream bfin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("cipherText.txt")));//To read the file in Binary Mode.
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    int BUFFERSIZE = 1024;
    byte[] readBytes = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];
    byte[] data = null;
    int totalRead = -1;
    while( (totalRead = bfin.read(readBytes))!=-1)
    {
        byte[] temp = new byte[(data == null ? totalRead : data.length)];
        System.arraycopy((data==null ? readBytes : data),0,temp,0, temp.length); 
        data = new byte[(data == null ? 0 : data.length) + totalRead];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, data, 0, temp.length);
        System.arraycopy(readBytes, 0, data, data.length - temp.length, totalRead);
    }
    if (data!=null)
    {
        byte[] newPlainText = cipher.doFinal(data);
        out2.write(newPlainText);
        out2.flush();
        System.out.println("DECRYPTED String:\n"+new String(newPlainText,"UTF8"));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No Data Found");
    }
    //String dt = new String(newPlainText, "UTF8");
    out2.close();
}
}
```

I hope this would help you in resolving the exception you getting ...